# How can I export my time series output to a table in my DB in R. (R Studio)

Tags: r, database

I have a forecast output from R and I want to export it to a table in my database. 
My output looks the below:

```
             Count
Jan 2017      590 
Feb 2017      680 
March 2017    568 
April 2017    789
```

How do I draft my syntax with,

`dbWriteTable(con, "myTableinMySQL", yourtable, append = TRUE)`

to achieve the below.

1. Do I create a table in my DB beforehand? Should they match the column names?
2. The month and year do not have any column name, how to get both the columns included in the table?

TIA.

Comment: (1) You are not required (by `DBI`) to create a table before uploading data, the function will create it (if you have permissions) and upload the data. (2) All columns *must* have column names, that's kind of a strict thing in databases. In fact, R requires all columns (in a frame) to have names. If it is unnamed, that suggests they are *row names*, in which case you need to assign them to their own column. In this case, they (month/year) are strings, so you will not be doing any date calculations with them, is that alright?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, no calculations, but I am planning to visualize it in a different tool for which my month/year becomes an axis value. So I require the Month/year column. Is there a way to change the row names to a column in R?

Comment: `x$r <- rownames(x)` works. There are helpers in some packages, such as `tibble::rownames_to_column`, which help (but do little more than that). There are many who argue row names are useless: they are little more than strings in a special column that is not handled as safely or consistently with other columns in the frame. If the row names are important enough, make them a formal column. (My opinion.)

Comment: These row names occurred as a result of my prediction algorithm. `x$r <- rownames(x)` - how do i implicate this here? `q=forecast(pi,h=12)` is my query where q gives the above output.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"implicate here"*, but if you mean "make it turn it into a column", just don't. Not every function in R is going to give you the perfectly-shaped/named `data.frame` output, some people disagree with the sentiment that row names are not important/usable, etc. If you want to upload it to a database, just turn the row names into a named column and upload it. Or discard the row names. Those are your choices. (BTW: `forecast::forecast` puts out an object, not necessarily a `data.frame`, so I don't know all of its components. Without your code, I know nothing.)

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks :)